# Mocking a REST service

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

There "will" be a REST API written in `Java` that I should connect to it from my Rails application. So I need the client and I am using `Net::HTTP`. But the problem is that the Java service is not written yet! It is in progress by other co-workers! But still I don't want to be blocked and want to somehow mock it or something and write my code.

I do know what the service uri will look like, what params it will have, what JSON response it will return, etc... but I just don't have the real working service to connect to.

Is there a way I can mock it and keep coding for my side? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at http://tomashanacek.github.io/mock-server/ - simple mock server for REST API

Answer (score 0):

I would find another operating REST service that you can connect to and get data from.  Once you have that code written, just adapt it to the service that your co-workers are writing afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try my mock server:
https://mockserver.codeplex.com/
It's easy to use and extend.